# How to delete a "Recurly" account completely from ruby api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

Can anyone please tell me how to delete a recurly account. As, I have tried with the following commands,

```
r = Recurly::Account.find(account_code)
r.delete
```

And also, I have tried with "r.destroy".

But, it only changing the state of recurly account from "active" to "closed" and not deleting the account completely.

I am using rails 2.3.11 for this application.

Answer (score 2):

As per the Recurly official  [documentation](http://docs.recurly.com/api/accounts#close-account) the account can only be closed.

Because you have the option to [reopen](http://docs.recurly.com/api/accounts#reopen-account) the account in future.

Answer (score 2):

Soundar is correct. I'll also note that if your account is still in sandbox mode, you can go to Site Settings and click "Clear Test Data" to clear out any test accounts, transactions, or coupon redemptions (configuration settings remain). In production mode, accounts cannot be deleted to retain their historical accounting data.

Comment: Presently, application is in "production" mode. Is there no other way to delete records completely in "production" mode.

Comment: Thank you for that Rachel, 6 years later this comment was super helpful.